# Low quality sound even with A2DP

Tags: sound, bluetooth, headphones

Laptop: Asus ROG GL703GS

OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Headphones: WH-1000XM3

Problem: I am able to connect the headphones in A2DP mode, but after listening for a while the quality goes worse. Note that it does NOT switch to HSP/HFP and it does NOT sound as HSP/HFP quality. Reconnecting solves the problem for a minute or two only. The problem persists no matter whether the sound comes from Spotify/YouTube.

**EDIT1** The output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsubs` is:

```
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] [8086:a370] (rev 10)
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] [8086:0034]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 13d3:56a2 IMC Networks USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0b05:1866 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. N-KEY Device
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Advice?

Comment: If you are using BT with 2.4 Wi-Fi, it is expected. Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: updated @Pilot6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest to disable BT Coexistence Technology that traditionally works poorly with Intel chips.

Run in a terminal:

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N"
```

and reboot.

That may help to solve the problem.

You can revert this setting by

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf
```

Comment: I'm testing it today! I will select it as an answer for now (as it seems to do the trick) and will get back if there are still problems. At some point it seemed to lag for a milisecond, but it didn't noticeably drop the quality.

Comment: OK, certainly it is better. However, the quality still decreases (during the milisecond lags), but much less. I wonder if there is anything else that can be done to improve the quality? @Pilot6

Comment: There is. Switch to 5 GHz Wi-Fi ;-) It is tricky for the hardware to download audio and sending it to BT using the same 2.4 band.